# Postman 403 Forbidden message

Tags: java, spring, rest, postman

I made some api with REST Spring. GET request works fine in Postman but when I try to do POST request I receive this error :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-09-25T06:39:27.226+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/cidashboard/projects"
}
```

This is my controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(ProjectController.PROJECT_URL)
public class ProjectController {

    public static final String PROJECT_URL = "/cidashboard/projects";

    private final ProjectService projectService;

    public ProjectController(ProjectService projectService) {
        this.projectService = projectService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    List<Project> getAllProjects(){
        return projectService.findAllProjects();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    Project getProjectById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return projectService.findProjectById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    void addProject(@RequestBody Project newProject) {
        projectService.saveProject(newProject);
    }
}
```

Security configuration
 initial I wanted to work with ldap, but in my application properties i left only the conection at database....................................................................................................................................................

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll();
//                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
//                .and()
//                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
//                .failureUrl("/login-error");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource(contextSource())
                .passwordCompare()
                //.passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/static/**"); // #3
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
        return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap://localhost:8389/"), "dc=springframework,dc=org");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add security config class code ?

Comment: Let me guess you don't include the CSRF token in your post request.

Comment: In my case was issue with token. I am sure, previously I used `Authorization` = `Basic <token>`, but this time it failed with 403. So, I spent 30 min trying to find out what is wrong, and finally just using plainly `Authorization` = `<token>` fixed it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Enable spring security with `@EnableWebSecurity` usage.By default enables `csrf` support, you have to disable it to prevent Forbidden errors.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http       //other configure params.
         .csrf().disable();
}
```

**PS:** 415 unsupported type  --> add to your mapping like this annotation for which type of data is sending from Postman.

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")
void addProject(@RequestBody Project newProject) {
    projectService.saveProject(newProject);
}
```

Comment: I added and now i recieve this error : 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: So your actually advice is to make the application less secure only for testing...

Comment: Unsupported media type about your sending type. Which type is sending from postman JSON or whatelse ?

Comment: @M.Deinum But he ignored the csrf , that means he dont need this token. if he used , csrf support is default .that means he dont wants to csrf token.

Comment: That is an assumption. The fact that he ignored the csrf token could very well be due to the fact he didn't know that csrf protection is enabled by default. Nonetheless giving the advice to make an application less secure is always a bad answer (imho that is).

Comment: Assumptions but i think true. Of course he can found about csrf usage. I said only how to prevent from this problem. I respect your think , but i dont think this downvote is right totaly. But thanks your suggests and opinions.

Comment: Drowny, @Consumes need a special dependency?

Comment: I added new configuration on `PostMapping` to my post. You can use `@PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")`

Comment: I receive this org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized.

Comment: Finally it work. I have a mistake in database. But work only with .csrf().disable(), and I didn't have to put @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE). Thanks a lot!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the `"User-Agent"` included in Headers section, If not add the `"User-Agent"` field

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to solve this issue without compromising security, you can send the xsrf-token with your request in postman.

1. Create a new environment in Postman (e.g. "local").
2. Create a new variable in this environment (e.g. "xsrf-token")
3. Go back to your request and make sure the right environment is selected on the top right corner ("local" in this case)
4. In your POST request, add a header with key "X-XSRF-TOKEN" and value "{{csrf-token}}"
5. In the "tests" tab, add following code:

```
var xsrfCookie = pm.cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
pm.environment.set("xsrf-token", xsrfCookie)
```

The first time you make this request, you will still get a 403, but you'll also receive a cookie with the xsrf-token. The script will copy this token in the environment variable and the next requests you'll make use the appropriate token.

Answer (score -1):

I I was also getting the same error. I found the solution using a different application, not postman {Insomnia REST Client}.
When I went back to postman after wondering, I realized that it is related to permissions in spring security. So after setting the permissions it will work.